# VB.NET SQL Query for deletion not executed

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, web-services, db2

I'm dealing with an odd issue, no one in my team was able to help me.

I've created a web service to delete content from a table. When I run this function from SOAP Center, everything is fine, values are deleted.

As soon as I call this function from my application, it is not working and nothing happen. I don't have any error and I tried to put return value to catch any error and nothing.

Can someone explain the difference in the execution if the issue come from this ?

Function in the WS

```vbnet
Public Function DELETE_VALUES() As Integer
    Dim db2Transaction As MsDb2Transaction
    Dim db2Command As MsDb2Command
    Dim oracleCommand As OracleCommand

    Using db2Connection As New MsDb2Connection(myConnectionString)
        Try
            db2Connection.Open()
            db2Transaction = db2Connection.BeginTransaction

            Dim sSqlDelete As String = String.Empty
            sSqlDelete += "DELETE FROM TABLE_DB2 "
            sSqlDelete += "WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y' "
            db2Command.Transaction = db2Transaction
            db2Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            ' Commit needed on our DB2 DB
            db2Transaction.Commit()
        Catch ex As MsDb2Exception
            db2Connection.Close()
            Return 8
        Finally
            db2Connection.Close()
        End Try
    End Using

    Using oracleConnection As New OracleConnection(myConnectionStringOracle)
        Try
            oracleConnection.Open()

            Dim sSqlDelete As String = String.Empty
            sSqlDelete += "DELETE FROM TABLE_ORACLE "
            sSqlDelete += "WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y' "
            oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            ' Commit is automatic on Oracle
        Catch ex As MsDb2Exception
            oracleConnection.Close()
            Return 9
        Finally
            oracleConnection.Close()
        End Try
    End Using

    Return 0
End Function
```

Function from my application

```vbnet
Public Function ValuesTreatment() As Integer
    WS_Functions.DELETE_VALUES()
    
    ' The rest of this function will add recent values
End Function
```

Comment: What is the SQL that you are executing from the function ? Can you try to give an invalid/wrong SQL and see if you get any message ?

Comment: DELETE FROM TABLE
WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y'

Simple delete like this one

I did a invalid sql query by putting a wrong table name and I have my return 7 as I expected

Comment: @aliitaqk - when are the commits taken?  If auto commit is on you don't have to explicitly commit as a separate step.  If it's off then you do or your changes are discarded by the DBRM.

Comment: You seem to think that we're clairvoyant. We can only go by the information you provide us and you have simply told us that the desired result of a multi-step process is not what you expect. It's up to you to determine where in that multistep process things go wrong. Put some tracing code and see exactly which steps are performed and whether they are using the correct data. For all we (and you) know, this has nothing to do with the data access code as you're not even getting that far.

Comment: Which database are you actually using? You tagged both Oracle and DB2. Please remove the extra tag.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - you can find my code in the post. I can get to the DB. When I try a simple select and try to extract a value, it's working

Comment: @Belayer I'm using both databases

Comment: We cannot do your debugging! If it works in one context, but 'does nothing' in a different context, it is __your job__ to determine precisely what is different, to debug each case using whatever debugging and tracing services are provided by your toolchain.

Comment: @mao Actually, I was not asking for a debugging, maybe my request led to this understanding. I'm not an DB expert and I'm still working on my skills. Thus, some thing on my side are not easy to understand and find. Senior dev in my client's company cannot help me and I was hoping that maybe someone faced the same issue or would have a logic understanding. If not, you are right, I'm the one who have to find the answer. Thank you anyway

Comment: Assuming I'm reading things correctly, Firstly, you're not doing anything with the sql command. You're missing a space in your SQL command (between the table name and Where), then what I suspect will happen it's skipping your exception handling as you appear to only be handing MsDb2Exception.  If this is the exact same service you're running from soap service, I'm stunned it work really.

Comment: @Hursey Thanks for your response. I've write the code again and not copy paste. But I indeed have spaces at the end of my sql strings (just edited now). I suspected right limitation depending on the environment. But this morning, I noticed it work once a day...

Comment: Yeah, still no idea how this is even working once a day.  You're creating the command text, but you're not doing anything with it.  You need db2Command.CommandText = sSqlDelete before you execute the command.  Right now you are executing an empty sql command.  Have a look at the return value from your ExecuteNonQuery, I will guarantee that returns 0 each and every time.